# How can I retrieve a list of specific person names from DBPedia by using SPARQL query in R

Tags: r, iteration, sparql, dbpedia

I am currently using the SPARQL package in R to query DBPedia and get the information for a list of specific person names. But I only know how to query one person or the "person category", such as

```
query= "SELECT *{
    dbpedia:Veit_Dietrich ?p ?o 
}"

qd=SPARQL(endpoint,query)
df=qd$results
```

Is there anyway to iterative query several names (a,b and c)  by only using one single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a query like this, the easiest thing is to use **values**.  E.g.,

```sql
select * { 
  values ?person { dbpedia:Johnny_Cash dbpedia:Johann_Sebastian_Bach }
  ?person ?p ?o 
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20*%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Fperson%20%7B%20dbpedia%3AJohnny_Cash%20dbpedia%3AJohann_Sebastian_Bach%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

I'm not familiar with R, but [hui pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30513620/how-can-i-retrieve-a-list-of-specific-person-names-from-dbpedia-by-using-sparql/30513923#comment49127354_30513923) that R's [**paste**](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html) function can be used to concatenate the list of URIs to produce the content for **values**.

Comment: Thx. But if there is about 300 names, the values should not be very feasible. Is there any way to use like variables, I tried to use variables, but it seems that it doesn't fit SPARQL...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking by "any way to use like variables".  **?person** *is* a variable.

Comment: Sorry. For example, if I have a list of 100 person names and I import the list  into R and I query each name in the list by SPARQL, such as: ft=function(b){
  for(i in 1:length(b)){  select * {dbpedia:b[i] ?p ?o 
}"  I know this is ugly and wrong, but I don't know how to modify it...

Comment: @hui I'm not familiar with R, but why not something like `"select * { values ?person { "+convertListToUris(persons)+" } ?person ?p ?o"`?

Comment: @hui I don't think Joshua is suggesting that that function is provided by R - but it should be easy to write one yourself.

Comment: @joshua@Jeen thx, I used "paste" function in R and now everything looks good : )